# How to decompress compressed image topic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, image-raw, compressedimage, compressed-image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello people,

I have a question on how to decompress image topics. I have a `/D435/color/image_raw/compressed` image and I am interested in decompressing it and get a new  `/D435/color/image_raw` topic. My search led me to the image_transport package but probably I am not using it correctly. I am interested in using the nodes it has because I have 0 knowledge of cpp and I can not use the api. So far I've tried this and I got the following warning.

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/D435/color/image_raw/compressed  raw out:=/D435/color/image_raw
```

> [ WARN] [1622914313.899141980]:
> [image_transport] It looks like you
> are trying to subscribe directly to a
> transport-specific image topic
> '/D435/color/image_raw/compressed', in
> which case you will likely get a
> connection error. Try subscribing to
> the base topic '/D435/color/image_raw'
> instead with parameter
> ~image_transport set to 'compressed'
> (on the command line,
> _image_transport:=compressed). See http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport
> for details.

Any idea how to cope with this or any other way to do it?? Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379664/how-to-decompress-compressed-image-topic?/) by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2021-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Listen to what the error says and instead try:

```
 rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/D435/color/image_raw  raw out:=/D435/color/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2021-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on 2021-06-08**:
Thank you for your solution.